# Wordpress custom url with variables

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

From:
`domain.com/ww/?profile=5&profile_page=apie-mane`

To:
`domain.com/ww/anketa/5/apie-mane`

I tried using `add_rewrite_rule` but it doesn't work how i want.

This is my current code:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^anketa/([0-9]+)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?id=29&profile=$matches[1]&profile_page=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
```

29 - my page id.

This code kind of works but it redirects me to `domain.com/ww/` (to page with 29 id). What i want is not to get redirected to `domain.com/ww/` i want to be in the same url e.g. `domain.com/ww/anketa/5/apie-mane`

**EDIT:** Website is on Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this rule in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ww/anketa/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /ww/?profile=$1&profile_page=$2 [L]
```

This should leave you with your desired URLs. Just make sure you clear your cache before testing it.